# Referring to a table in LaTeX

Tags: latex

How can you refer to a table number such that you get `Table 7` for instance?

Sample data

```
Table \ref{table:questions} lorem lorem ipsun.

\begin{table}
\label{table:questions}
\begin{tabular}{| p{5cm} | p{5cm} | p{5cm} |}
  -- cut --
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I get

```
Table 2.5 lorem lorem ipsun.
```

where 2.5 is the chapter number.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about LaTeX.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been migrated to tex.SX.com?

Answer (score 428, accepted):

You must place the label after a caption in order to for `label` to store the table's number, not the chapter's number.

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{| p{5cm} | p{5cm} | p{5cm} |}
  -- cut --
\end{tabular}
\caption{My table}
\label{table:kysymys}
\end{table}

Table \ref{table:kysymys} on page \pageref{table:kysymys} refers to the ...
```

Comment: For some reason, this pushes the table and caption to the bottom of the page, resulting in the caption to be the last sentence on the page, where the table sits nicely on top of the caption. _How can I remedy  this, so that it just sits underneath the last typed sentence?_ I suspect it's to do with the `\beign{table}` and `\end{table}` command...

Comment: @3kstc You might try asking at https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @3kstc, i had the same problem, solved by changing \begin{table} to \begin{table}[H] from \usepackage{float}

Comment: @Anton Yes! I did that just that, it resolved all my problems

Comment: 2019 Almost, the accepted answer is still valid. Ten years later. Just updating as I myself was skeptical at first.

Comment: Another note: if you were trying to put your table in a `figure` . . . *don't*. Merely `table` produces the desired effect.

Comment: Placing the \caption before \begin{tabular} resolved the problem for me by placing the caption above the table.

Comment: mine put '??' instead of reference, anybody knows?